# Own Malloc implementation freeze at brk

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, free, brk

for practice I'm currently trying to write my own malloc function in c.
So my question is, after some allocation from the heap my program will freeze. I found the code segment which will couse the freeze and it'll freeze when i call the brk sys call. I allready tried to unlock my mutex there but this didn't work. To test it i wrote a permanent loop and allocate memory in an array and freed it randomly.

```
static list *head = NULL;
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

typedef struct list
{         
  size_t size_;                
  int free_;                  
  struct list *next_;      
  struct list *previouse_;
} block;

void blockAdd(block *href, size_t size)
{
  href->free_ = FALSE;
  href->next_ = NULL;
  href->previouse_ = NULL;

  if (!head || head > href)
  {
    if (head)
    {
      head->previouse_ = href;
    }
    href->size_ = size + sizeof(block);
    href->next_ = head;
    head = href;
  }
  else
  {
    href->next_ = NULL;
    block *current = head;

    while (current->next_ && current->next_ < href)
    {
      current = current->next_;
    }
    href->size_ = size + sizeof(block);
    href->next_ = current->next_;
    href->previouse_ = current;
    current->next_ = href;
  }
}

void *findExactSizeMatch(size_t size)
{
  block *href = head;
  size_t t = size + sizeof(block);

  while (href)
  {
    if (href->size_ == (size + sizeof(block)) && href->free_)
    {
      href->free_ = FALSE;
      return href;
    }
    href = href->next_;
  }
  return NULL;
}

void *findLagerBlock(size_t size)
{
  block *href = head;

  while (href)
  {
    if (href->free_ && href->size_ > size)
    {
      return split(href, size);
    }
    href = href->next_;
  }

  return NULL;
}

void *allocateMemory(size_t size)
{
  block *new_block = sbrk(BLOCK_SIZE(size));

  if (new_block == SBRK_FAILED)
  {
    exit(1);
  }
  blockAdd(new_block, size);

  return new_block;
}

bool checkAllFree()
{
  block *href = head;

  while (href)
  {
    if (!href->free_)
    {
      return FALSE;
    }
    href = href->next_;
  }
  return TRUE;
}

void freeList(block *ptr)
{
  if (checkAllFree())
  {
    if (brk(ptr) == BRK_FAILED)
    {
     exit(1);
    }
    head = NULL;
  }
}

void merge()
{
  block *href = head;

  while (href && href->next_)
  {
    if (href->free_ && href->next_->free_)
    {
      href->size_ = href->next_->size_;
      href->next_ = href->next_->next_;
    }
    href = href->next_;
  }
}

//--------------------------Here it makes some strange things
shrinkHeap()
{
  block *href = head;

  while (href && href->next_)
  {
    href = href->next_;
  }

  if (href && href->free_)
  {
    if (brk(href) == BRK_FAILED)
    {
      exit(1);
    }
    href->previouse_->next_ = href->next_;
  }
}

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
  if (!size)
  {
    return NULL;
  }
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  block *new_list = NULL;

  new_list = findExactSizeMatch(size);
  if (new_list)
  {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return new_list + sizeof(block);
  }

  new_list = allocateMemory(size);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  return new_list + sizeof(block);
}

void free(void *ptr)
{
  if (!ptr || !head)
  {
    return;
  }
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  block *pref = ptr - sizeof(block);

  pref->free_ = TRUE;

  freeList(pref);
  shrinkHeap();
  merge();

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

I don't know why, but brk freeze my program.

Thx for your help!

Comment: `return new_list + sizeof(block);` What type is `new_list`? What does addition do to that type? You are overrunning the memory you allocated.

Comment: regarding: `if (brk(ptr) == BRK_FAILED)
    {
     exit(1);
    }`  You really need to inform the user of what happened rather than immediately exiting the application.  Also, the C version of `malloc()`, etc return NULL when they fail, not exit the application

Comment: Please post the definition of `BLOCK_DATA`

Comment: Where is the freeze occurring?  Use a debugger to see where it is blocked or looping.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz new_list is a struct, which i defined at the top of my code. Ok and how can i avoid this problem? Or what could be the problem with the shrinkHeap function? I just set the brk if the last element is free or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- in `blockAdd`, you fail to update `href->next_->previouse_` if `href->next_` is not `NULL` in the `else` branch.
- `findLagerSize` should be changed to `findLargerSize` and should use `size + sizeof(block)` to locate an appropriate block of memory.
- `allocateMemory` is incorrect too: the size passed to `sbrk` should include `sizeof(block)` extra bytes, the block thus allocated should be inserted into the heap and split if it is larger than `size + sizeof(block)`.
- in `freeList`, in case `checkAllFree()` returns true, you should call `brk(head)`, not `brk(ptr)`.
- in `merge`, you do not update `href->size` correctly: you should combine the sizes. Furthermore you do not upate `href-_next->previouse_`.
- The prototype for `shrinkHeap` should have a return type and an argument list:

  ```
  void shrinkHeap(void)
  ```
- In `shrinkHeap` you must update the link **before** calling `brk` as the pointer may become invalid after the call. Furthermore, you must test if `href->previouse_` is not `NULL` and this update can be simplified as:

  ```
      if (href->previouse_ != NULL)
          href->previouse_->next_ = NULL;
  ```
- Your `malloc` function has a flaw: `return new_list + sizeof(block);` does not return the pointer to the allocated block, but one much farther away, causing the application to write beyond the end of the allocated block, potentially corrupting the arena. Furthermore, the pointer computed by free does not point to the `block`, causing further corruption of the arena even if the program did not write to the memory block and invoking undefined behavior.

  In both places in `malloc()`, you should write this instead:

  ```
      return new_list + 1;
  ```
- Similarly in `free()`, but not necessarily causing an error, you should avoid performing arithmetics on `void` pointers, cast them as `unsigned char *` for portable code:

  ```
  block *pref = (void *)((unsigned char*)ptr - sizeof(block));
  ```

  Or perform the arithmetics after proper typing:

  ```
  block *pref = ptr;
  ptr -= 1;
  ```

Here is a modified version:

```c
static struct list *head = NULL;
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

typedef struct list {
    size_t size_;           // block size, including header
    int free_;              // free indicator, true or false
    struct list *next_;
    struct list *previouse_;
} block;

void blockAdd(block *href, size_t size) {
    href->free_ = FALSE;
    href->size_ = size + sizeof(block);
    href->next_ = NULL;
    href->previouse_ = NULL;

    if (!head || head > href) {
        if (head) {
            head->previouse_ = href;
        }
        href->next_ = head;
        head = href;
    } else {
        block *current = head;
        while (current->next_ && current->next_ < href) {
            current = current->next_;
        }
        href->next_ = current->next_;
        if (href->next_) {
            href->next_->previouse_ = href;
        }
        href->previouse_ = current;
        current->next_ = href;
    }
}

void *findExactSizeMatch(size_t size) {
    block *href = head;
    size_t t = size + sizeof(block);

    while (href) {
        if (href->free_ && href->size_ == t) {
            href->free_ = FALSE;
            return href;
        }
        href = href->next_;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *findLargerBlock(size_t size) {
    block *href = head;
    size_t t = size + sizeof(block);

    while (href) {
        if (href->free_ && href->size_ > t) {
            return split(href, size);
        }
        href = href->next_;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *allocateMemory(size_t size) {
    /* should add size of `block` */
    block *new_block = sbrk(BLOCK_SIZE(size));

    if (new_block == SBRK_FAILED) {
        exit(1);
    }
    /* should split new_block if BLOCK_SIZE(size) > size */
    blockAdd(new_block, size);

    return new_block;
}

bool checkAllFree() {
    block *href = head;

    while (href) {
        if (!href->free_) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        href = href->next_;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void freeList(block *ptr) {
    if (checkAllFree()) {
        if (brk(head) == BRK_FAILED) {
            exit(1);
        }
        head = NULL;
    }
}

void merge(void) {
    block *href = head;

    while (href && href->next_) {
        if (href->free_ && href->next_->free_) {
            href->size_ += href->next_->size_;
            href->next_ = href->next_->next_;
            href->next_->previouse_ = href;
        }
        href = href->next_;
    }
}

void shrinkHeap(void) {
    block *href = head;

    if (href) {
        while (href->next_) {
            href = href->next_;
        }
        if (href->free_) {
            if (href->previouse_ != NULL) {
                href->previouse_->next_ = NULL;
            }
            if (brk(href) == BRK_FAILED) {
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}

void *malloc(size_t size) {
    if (!size) {
        return NULL;
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    block *new_list = findExactSizeMatch(size);
    if (new_list == NULL) {
        new_list = findLargerSize(size);
    }
    if (new_list == NULL) {
        new_list = allocateMemory(size);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    if (new_list)
        return new_list += 1;
    else
        return NULL;
}

void free(void *ptr) {
    if (!ptr || !head) {
        return;
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    block *pref = ptr;
    pref -= 1;
    pref->free_ = TRUE;

    freeList(pref);
    merge();
    shrinkHeap();

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```